# Play for Scala: Scala object as DAO

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scala, object, playframework, slick

I am used to frameworks like Ruby on Rails or Laravel in PHP where I have models like `User` and when I want to make a query to the model (for example, to get all the users in the database) I do something like `User::all()`.

I'm new to Play for Scala and Slick, and all the projects and documentation I've already seen use a DAO for accessing the database through a model. I've thought that a Scala `object` is what I need (or at least I am accustomed to) so I don't need to inject DAO classes everywhere.

With a DAO I do something like this:

```
class Application @Inject()(adminDAO: AdminDAO) extends Controller {
  def index = Action.async {
    adminDAO.all() map { case admins =>
      Ok(Json.toJson(admins))
    }
  }
}
```

And with an object (and no idea) I expect to do something like this:

```
class Application extends Controller {
  def index = Action.async {
    Admin.all() map { case admins =>
      Ok(Json.toJson(admins))
    }
  }
}
```

Trying to implement the "DAO" `object` I have found almost impossible to to inject the Play `Application` context without using `Play.current` which is deprecated. That kind of deprecation and the absence of a way of injecting the context (or at least I haven't found it) sounds strange to me. I'm starting to think that I'm thinking it the wrong way. Is it really a good idea to use a Scala `object` as DAO?

Comment: You can also have a look at [Anorm](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAnorm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It comes down to dependency injection (DI) vs hardcoding dependencies. Your first example makes use of DI, your second one hardcodes the dependency against the `Admin` DAO. The Play team has decided to go with DI in recent releases in an effort to remove global state (for a discussion why global state is a bad thing see [here for example](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)):

> Play now, out of the box, uses dependency injection provided by Guice.
>   This is part of a long term strategy to remove global state out of
>   Play, which we hope to complete in the Play 3.0 release.

[Source](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration24)

Hence the right way when it comes to Play is your example 1, using an object and hence a hardcoded dependency is indeed inadvisable purely based on the fact that you work against play (however DI has many advantages too).

I'm not well versed in Ruby, but as far as I know DI with frameworks (e.g. Guice) as it comes in Java/Scala isn't needed because Ruby has certain language features to solve the problem differently, which might be why you are wondering about the whole point of it all. I recommend you read a bit about dependency injection in a Java/Scala context, that should clear up how it works, what problems it solves and what the (dis)advantages are (and since you know Ruby, why it isn't needed in Ruby in the same way).

> Trying to implement the "DAO" object I have found almost impossible to
>   to inject the Play Application context without using Play.current
>   which is deprecated. That kind of deprecation and the absence of a way
>   of injecting the context (or at least I haven't found it) sounds
>   strange to me.

You should be able to simply inject the application context into your DAO, e.g. like this:

```
class AdminDao @Inject()(val application : Application) {
```

and then you have the application available. This is the equivalent to the deprecated

```
val application = Play.current
```

In both cases you capture the running `Application`. The depencency injection framework behind it all makes sure that dependencies are resolved recursively, i.e. when you depend on your DAO in a controller it notes that the DAO itself depends on the application. It resolves the application, injects it into a new DAO instance and finally injects that into your controller.

And last but not least many ways lead to rome as usual: Maybe [ActiveSlick](http://www.strongtyped.io/active-slick/) is something that you find useful (disclaimer: Haven't tried it myself).

Comment: Thank for the clarification for the first part (DI vs global state), but in the second part of the response, the problem is that I need the `Application` context inside a Scala `object` so I don't have any constructor available to inject the dependency. With the DAO using a `class` there is no problem at all. How would you solve it?

Comment: You don't want to use an object because then you use global state again (-> one DAO instance used by all classes which depend on it). You want a class, that way the framework generates individual DAO instances for every class which depends on it -> no more global state. DI in a play context comes with the whole class-constructor-inject pattern, as anoying as it is to write (I agree here). Injecting into objects simply doesn't work because the framework can't generate the instances and resolve dependencies.

Comment: Perfect! thank you for such a deep response, I will use classes as DAO as it's the preferred way by Play.